# Is it possible to use closures in AS2 like in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, actionscript-2, closures

I am wondering if it is possible to create a closure in ActionScript2 like it is possible in Javascript.
This doesn't work:

```
var util = function(){
   var init = function(){
      trace(this + ': util'); // i want to know this thing works!
      var myUtils = new MyAS2Utils();  // load some stuff
      var url = myUtils.getURLInSomeReallyCoolWay();  // really, this is all fluff isn't it?
      myAwesomeButton.onRelease = function(){
          getURL(url,"_blank");
      }
    }
    // and return the goods
    return {
       init : function(){
           init();
       }    
    }
}();

// now call the init funciton
util.init();
```

I have tried this other ways but it never works.  I hope it's possible because if I'm forced to use AS2, I want to at least have a little fun with it :)
thanks!
aaron

Comment: "This doesn't work:" - Can you be more specific about your *goal*?

Comment: my goal is to be able to instantiate the object without calling the constructor.  "This doesn't work" means that when compile my swf, the call to util.init() does nothing.  No trace, no button.onRelease, nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article articulates how one can use anonymous functions to pass around scopes - which is what I was really looking for in the first place - I just didn't know it ;)
http://studiokoi.com/blog/article/making_anonymous_functions_and_closures_work_in_actionscript_20

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to use actionscript as if it were javascript-style object oriented programming. The reason you need to use closures in javascript is because javascript lacks the namespacing abilities of actionscript and other classical languages. Its the only way to create protected properties and methods in javascript.

I highly recommend you create an external class for your util objects, that way they are completely reusable for other projects. But if you want to create a single, temporary object you can do this:

```
var util = new Object();
    util.myUtils = new BlaBla();
    util.property = myUtils.blaBlaBla();
    util.init = function() {
      //Do some stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Your example is really strange. 
But I agree with what you are saying.  There are a few ways to create private props and methods in AS2, ex. external classes.  I just wanted to know if you could implement it with closures.  I they are freaking awesome.